# Special characters are inserting as �� into Oracle database using sqlloader

Tags: database, oracle, sql-loader

I'm unable to insert Japanese characters into Oracle database using sqlloader.

Here I'm using SQLloader (11.2 version) and destination database version is 11.2.0.3. I tried UTF8 and NVARCHAR option. Can we use different sqlloader and database versions?

Comment: Japanese characters are encoded in UTF8. Is your source file encoding is UTF-8?

Comment: Do you run SQL loader in Windows or Linux?

Comment: What is the encoding of your file? It might be UTF-8 but others e.g. UTF-16 or [Windows-932](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932_(Microsoft_Windows)) could be also possible.

Comment: @Tejash- I have tried with UTF-8 but no luck

Comment: What do you mean by "I have tried with UTF-8"? Please answer my questions, then I will you provide the solution.